# Custom sorting order in map, independent of identity

Tags: java

I have four pieces of information (a, b, c, d) that go together (like the columns in database table).

The combination of a and b is unique (like the primary key in a database table)

```
class MyClass {
    private String a, b, c, d; //getters & setters omitted
}

class Key {
    private String a, b; //getters & setters & equals & hashcode omitted

    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        Key key2 = (Key) obj;
        if (!this.a.equals(key2.a))
            return this.a.compareTo(key2.a);
        else
            return this.b.compareTo(key2.b);
    }
}

class Main {
    private Map<Key, MyClass> map = new TreeMap();

    void populateMap() {
        for each item in the source {
            map.put new Key(a, b), new MyClass(a, b, c, d);
        }
    }
}
```

When I iterate over this map the rows are sorted first by field a and then by b.
But I would like to order by a -> c -> b.

I could add c to my Key class and modify the compareTo function accordingly. But that feels wrong. A key is an identifier. And c is not needed to identify a row.

How should I go about modifying this code so that (a, b) is the identifier (that equals & hashcode are based on). But my map stores the information in the order a -> c -> b?

Comment: Define a `Comparator<Key>` that implements the ordering you want. However: [Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: Only way to sort the data is key you cannot sort on value in map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sort something in java what you need are basically two things:

- object must be **comparable**
- a Comparator object to compare pairs

with these two things you can do whatever you want:

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {

@Ovveride
public int compare(MyClass other) {
    if(this.a.compareTo(other.getA()) != 0)
      return this.a.compareTo(other.getA());
    if(this.c.compareTo(other.getC()) != 0)
      return this.c.compareTo(other.getC());
    return return this.b.compareTo(other.getB());
}
}
```

in main class

```
// you can sort only Collections so let's say you want to sort values
Collections.sort(mapValues, new Comparator<MyClass> () {
    @Ovveride
    public int compareTo(MyClass c1, MyClass c2) {
       return c1.compare(c2);
    }
});
```

As I said you can sort only Collection and TreeMap naturally order by key (if the key is Comparable) so think about store your information in a List/Set or put and then retrieve your values like I wrote before. If you want to order in put you need to pass every elements (a,b,c) but keep in mind that sorting after every put is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the entries (`Map.Entry<Key, MyClass>`) of your map then you can use `compairingByValue`

```
 map.entrySet().stream().sorted(comparingByValue());
```

and implement a `compareTo` method in `MyClass` that sorts in the order you want, a->c->b.